# Python request function won't download entire file

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm creating a python function to download a .zip file from Kaggle (I don't want to use the Kaggle API) with the request library. However the .zip file don't have a `content-length` header, so I can't check the size of the kaggle .zip file before downloading it.

So now my function looks like this, but it only downloads 5465 (6KB) of the entire 700MB file.

```
url = "https://www.kaggle.com/c/dog-breed-identification/download-all"
filename = "stanford-dogs.zip"
save_path = os.path.join(base_dir, filename)

def download_zip(url, save_path, chunk_size=128):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    
    with open(save_path, 'wb') as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
            fd.write(chunk)

download_url(url, path)
```

Comment: You don't download the zip file but an html page

Comment: The full url is something like `'https://storage.googleapis.com/kaggle-competitions-data/kaggle-v2/7327/861871/bundle/archive.zip?GoogleAccessId=...&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B+filename%3Ddog-breed-identification.zip'`

Comment: Thx, don't know how I missed that. @Corralien